# SQL Server - Find Minimum Value by Minute within Day Grouped by Symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a snippet of the single table I am operating on. The table contains a total of 15 different symbols, spanning 3 years (CurrDate) and approximately 370 Minutes (PRMinute) in each day. I am attempting a query that will show me the lowest value for each symbol, each day and display the minute (PRMinute) that low took place.

```
Symbol  CurrDate    PRMinute    PROpen    PRHigh    PRLow   PRClose
SLV     2013-07-09  1           18.55     18.56     18.55   18.555
TLT     2013-07-09  1           107.45    107.45    107.45  107.45
UCO     2013-07-09  1           34.10     34.10     34.10   34.10
!COMP   2013-07-10  1           3502.11   3503.41   3502.00 3503.17
!DJI    2013-07-10  1           15298.03  15315.86  15297.07
!GSPC   2013-07-10  1           1651.56   1652.21   1651.56 1652.09 0
!RUT    2013-07-10  1           1017.69   1017.87   1017.69 1017.87 0

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IntradayInput](
    [Symbol] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CurrDate] [date] NULL,
    [PRMinute] [smallint] NULL,
    [PROpen] [money] NULL,
    [PRHigh] [money] NULL,
    [PRLow] [money] NULL,
    [PRClose] [money] NULL,
    [PRVol] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: So, are we just interested in the `PRLow` column and ignoring the other `PRxxx` columns?

Comment: wont a simple aggregation of prminute work ?

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately I want to the lowest PRLow and the highest PRHigh of each day. I asked for just the PRLow above because if I get that syntax correct I can likely figure out how to do it for PRHigh too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this in SQL Server is to use `row_number()`:

```
select ii.*
from (select ii.*,
             row_number() over (partition by symbol, currdate 
                                order by prlow asc end) as seqnum
      from IntradayInput ii
     ) ii
where seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that `prlow` contains the information on the lowest value.  There is no column called `value`.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what I wanted. Now I will figure out how to do for PRHigh as well. I do not care if it's 2 SQL statements or 1 to accomplish both. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Gordon's answer, but is does not use a ranking function.

```
SELECT [Symbol], [CurrDate], MIN([PRLow]) AS Min_PRLow
  , (SELECT MIN([PRMinute]) FROM [IntradayInput] mi 
       WHERE mi.[Symbol]=i.[Symbol] AND mi.[CurrDate]=i.[CurrDate] 
         AND mi.PRLow=MIN(i.[PRLow])) AS PRMinute
  FROM [IntradayInput] i GROUP BY [Symbol],[CurrDate]
```